# what happens to session when user click back button on browser?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session

I have a trouble with my website:
I create a string delete = null in my jsp file. When use click delete button, I check delete in session, if session_delete != null, I'll remove delete attribute in session and will alert somthing.  After that, user click to change another page, then click back button on browser to back previous page and alert appear again. 
So please tell me what happen to when user click back button on browser?
Thank you so much

```
String success_add= null;
if(session.getAttribute("success_delete")!=null)
    {
        success_delete= session.getAttribute("success_delete").toString();
        session.removeAttribute("success_delete");
        if(success_delete.equals("1"))
        {
%>
    <script>
        alertify.alert("Delete success");
    </script> 
<%
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to send to jsp with warning and a link back and log on again ...
or..
make a tag library when you send to the servlet , return with an IF value to cancel the rest of the page and only show the tag.
(TAG with logout and link to login).

when you try to go back , you will go through the servlet and servlet is denied.